Format ADF test result in R Markdown and knit to pdf
I'm trying to incorporate the result in rmarkdown when kniting the file:
Below are my code:
```{r, Test for unit root, echo=F, include = T, message= F, warning=F}
#ADF test
adf.test(output_day$output)
```

but it returns error: You can't use macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. How should i fix this the result?
I guess I guess I cannot directly include it without proper latex formatting. May I ask what should I do?

Would you mind to extend your question with sample of output_day or similar data, please?

I usually don't name my chunks with spaces, and I usually don't put the comma after r when naming the chunk. You've got "Test for unit root" as the name of the chunk. Try using underscores.
